# Material UI <TableRow component={Link}> TypeScript error TS2769

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm creating a React SPA using Typescript and Material UI. I'm trying to add a table were each row is a link. This Link component is from React Router. My Table look similar to this (removed a lot of code to give a simplified version).

```
<Table>
  {data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <TableRow component={Link} to="/example">
        <TableCell></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
</Table>
```

This works in a development environment, but the project can't be built due to the error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TableRowProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type '"abbr" | "address" | "article" | "aside" | "b" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "caption" | "cite" | "code" | "dd" | "del" | "details" | "dfn" | "div" | "dt" | "em" | "figcaption" | ... 45 more ... | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>, any>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Property 'to' is missing in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>' but required in type 'Readonly<LinkProps<any>>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<TableRowProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type '"abbr" | "address" | "article" | "aside" | "b" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "caption" | "cite" | "code" | "dd" | "del" | "details" | "dfn" | "div" | "dt" | "em" | "figcaption" | ... 45 more ... | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>, any>'.
```

I'm stumped as to how I solve this problem. Through a few searches, then it seems this problem is only in TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error basically says that the props of `Link`s and table rows are incompatible.

If you want your table rows to have linky clickability, you could add an `onClick` handler using the `react-router` `history` object, e.g. using [the `useHistory` hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

Or if you want to live on the edge, you could probably just tell TypeScript to leave you alone with a cast like

```
<TableRow component={Link as any} to="/example">
```

but then you're naturally on your own as far as type safety is concerned.

Comment: I was using a onClick function, but then the user doesn't see where the link is taking them